# Can you apply for an Indian e-Visa if you have already have a valid Indian visa in your passport?

Tags: india, tourist-visas

I am currently traveling out of India but coming back soon. I will have some days left in my current visa by the time I come back, but I will need more time there. I can have enough time if I enter with a new electronic visa (2 months) but I am not sure if I can apply for one if I have one regular tourist visa still valid?

Comment: I've heard the e-visa process is fairly painless compared to the traditional visa. So I'd be inclined to give it a go and see if it comes through. However not if the tourist visa will still be valid when entering the country. Trying to enter with 2 visas could raise all sorts of questions...